# Airflow dag run never ends

Tags: airflow

```
def extract():
    df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv')
    client_id='***'
    client_secret='***'

    auth_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)


    album_names = []

    for album_id in df['album_id']:
        album = sp.album(album_id)
        album_name = album['name']
        album_names.append(album_name)

    df['Album_name'] = album_name
    print(df.head())
```

My dag is not ending. It keeps running. I tried giving full path to csv or moving csv to airflow/dags folder. I use virtual environment for airflow and my os mac m1. When I run code block on my local it runs, but when i run it on airflow webserver it doesnt end.

Comment: add some logs to see in where its stuck. after pd.read / spotipy.Spotify for example.